# Replace all completely black frames with interpolated frames

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editor, software-recommendation, filter

Due to a bug with Nvidia Shadowplay, I have a bunch of videos that [look like this](https://gfycat.com/uglymerryarctichare).  A bunch of random frames have been replaced with pure black frames.

I'd like to fix one of these videos to remove the flickering.  I saw an answer [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/23589/replace-black-frames-with-previous-frames) which suggests the following ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf blackframe=0,metadata=select:key=lavfi.blackframe.pblack:value=50:function=less -vsync cfr -c:a copy out.mp4
```

However, this replaces all the black frames with the most recent non-black frame, which makes the video look like a slideshow.

Is there any way to use a similar ffmpeg command (or any other tool) to use motion interpolation to fix the missing frames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After poring over the documentation all weekend, I figured out how to use the minterpolate filter to do motion interpolation.  The full command is

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf blackframe=0,metadata=select:key=lavfi.blackframe.pblack:value=50:function=less,minterpolate=mi_mode=mci:mc_mode=aobmc:me_mode=bidir:vsbmc=1:me=fss -c:a copy out.mp4
```

These were the settings that gave me the best-looking results.  If these are too slow for you, you can try something like

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf blackframe=0,metadata=select:key=lavfi.blackframe.pblack:value=50:function=less,minterpolate=mi_mode=mci:mc_mode=obmc:me_mode=bilat:vsbmc=0:me=tdls -c:a copy out.mp4
```

which went about 3x as fast in my testing.  You can find the documentation on the different minterpolate options [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#minterpolate).

Answer (score 1):

After removing the black frames, you can insert the framerate filter to fill the gaps with blended frames.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf blackframe=0,metadata=select:key=lavfi.blackframe.pblack:value=50:function=less,framerate=fps=60000/1001 -c:a copy out.mp4
```

See docs for framerate filter. The filter will produce a CFR stream so vsync is not required.

Comment: This appears to fade out the previous frame and fade in the next one _(either that or the motion interpolation algorithm is extremely poor)_.  While it's definitely better than just holding a still frame, the results are still not great.  I'll accept this if no one finds anything better...

Comment: The filter performs blending, so no motion interpolation. You can try the [minterpolate](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#minterpolate) filter instead of framerate but it will be slow.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to minterpolate! It works better than the 'framerate' filter, except in areas with fast movement or lots of consecutive missing frames.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about FFMPEG, but it wouldn't hurt to try the free version of DaVinci Resolve.  From page 1351 of the user manual (yes, quite TLDR):

> **RepairFrame, Tween**
>
> The Tween and Repair Frame nodes are different from
> standard optical flow nodes because they have the OpticalFlow analysis
> and motion vector generation built in. Tween will compare two frames
> and create an in-between frame, which is good for recreating a missing
> or flawed frame. Repair Frame will look at frames on either side of
> the current frame and repair scratches, dust marks, and so on. Because
> these nodes work with flow values between non-sequential frames, they
> cannot use the optical flow stored in the input image’s
> Vector/BackVector channels, but rather must regenerate the flow of
> each frame, do their processing, and then destroy the flow channels.
> This being the case, these nodes are computationally expensive. For
> more information on Tween or Repair Frame see the Nodes Reference
> guide.

Comment: It seems "RepairFrame" has been renamed to "Remove dust and scratches" in the latest version?  I tried it but it didn't work at all.

Comment: Works fine for me.  It's not called dust and scratches.  It's in the fusion tab.  Type shift+spacebar with the node editor active, and start typing "repairframe" or check under the "optical flow" subcategory of "tools" in the Effects Library.  If you don't see it there, it's a paid version only feature, in which case, I apologize for sending you on a wild goose chase.  It's hard to remember which things are and which aren't.  There isn't much that you can't do with  the free version, but every once in a while, you run into something.